# getting abort messege wiht "heap corruption detected" in android kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, abort, heap-corruption

I was trying to run youtube through browser on my device which is based on ARM architecture and after 20-30 minutes i am getting abort message and saying heap is corrupted. I am not getting any clue why heap is getting corrupted ? and how can I trace and dig the problem here? and how to fix?

```
I/DEBUG   (  809): pid: 813, tid: 1839, name: OMXCallbackDisp  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
I/DEBUG   (  809): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (  809): Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by (null)'
W/NativeCrashListener( 1126): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 813
D/dalvikvm( 1126): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 18% free 7104K/8656K, paused 20ms+28ms, total 277ms
I/DEBUG   (  809): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #00  pc 00021e58  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #01  pc 00012ea9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #02  pc 000130bd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #03  pc 00011df3  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #04  pc 0002170c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #05  pc 000128d9  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #06  pc 0000efe5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #07  pc 0000f69f  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #08  pc 00010d2f  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4250)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #09  pc 0000dae7  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #10  pc 0000b775  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SharedBuffer::alloc(unsigned int)+8)
I/DEBUG   (  809):     #11  pc 0000de69  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::VectorImpl::_shrink(unsigned int, unsigned int)+80)
```